# Wierdest thing ever: Boolean turns false after if statement?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, performance

**If this all seems confusing, ignore what I am saying, and look at the code and the section titled "Heres the weird part". Also, take a look at my log at the bottom.**

So basically, I am using a Shared Preference to do something only **once**.  **Here's what I do:**

1. Check whether the shared preference is false, this is it's default value
2. If so, change the shared preference to true when the user clicks "Never show again", that way the if statement won't go through.

**So if the user doesn't have location enabled, I check a shared preference and see if they want me to display the dialog, if the shared preference is false, I display it.**

```
    LocationManager locationManager = 
         (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

      if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) &&
         !locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) && 
         dialogPrefs.getBoolean("show", false) == false) {

           Log.v(TAG, dialogPrefs.getBoolean("show", false) +" GET BOOLEAN");

           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location not enabled ")
                        .setMessage("Blah")
                        .setNegativeButton("Remind again when I come to this activity", null)
                        .setNeutralButton("Don't show again...EVER!!!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialogEditor.putBoolean("show", true);
                                dialogEditor.commit();


                                Log.v(TAG, dialogPrefs.getBoolean("show", false) +" GET BOOLEAN");
                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //All location services are disabled
                                Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
                            }
                        }).show();

            }
```

Notice my logs.

### HERES THE WEIRD PART:

The if statement **ALWAYS** goes through...In my log, I check the value of the `dialogPrefs.getBoolean` after commiting the changes the first time, and it is **true** (which is good)! Then, suddenly, the method gets called again, and `dialogPrefs.getBoolean` is FALSE!

Why is this boolean changing? This is the weirdest thing ever, as it is such a simple problem, and is behaving in an unexpected way.

### My logcat looks like this:

```
V/myTag: false GET BOOLEAN //This is when the popup comes
V/myTag: true GET BOOLEAN //After I change value
V/myTag: false GET BOOLEAN //AFTER COMING BACK TO ACTIVITY!! WHY FALSE AGAIN!?!?
```

Edit:

I initialize in `onCreate`:

```
dialogPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); 

dialogEditor = dialogPrefs.edit();
```

Comment: How are you initializing `dialogPrefs`/`dialogEditor`?

Comment: @karaokyo Thanks for the reply! I initialize it in the `onCreate` method like so:

Comment: @karaokyo   `dialogPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        dialogEditor = dialogPrefs.edit();`

Comment: Add that to the question. Don't use a comment for the sake of future readers.

Comment: I understand your excitement and frustration, but would it be possible to remove the allcaps text for readability?

Comment: @ErikPragt Of course, I'm sorry if it wasn't very legible. I will edit it.

Comment: @glee8e Alright, I will edit it! :)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia where do you initialize the value of `"show"`? I understand that you initialize `dialogPrefs` in `onCreate`, but what about the value of `show`?

Comment: where are you calling this code LocationManager locationManager .....

Comment: @gj_ I don't initialize the value of "show". It is just a string that represents my boolean, right?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia sorry for my wording, what I mean is, where do you first set the value of boolean which has the key of `show`?

Comment: @gj_ I never explicitly set it, until the user clicks on "Dont show again". Otherwise, I just compare by checking if it is still at its default value of false.

Comment: @gj_ Should I explicitly set it? If so, how? Feel free to post an answer! :)

Comment: Difficult to know the reason. Just try once as below . Inplace of getApplicationContext  write Activityname. this                                    dialogPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityName.this);

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I have another question, where is your third log? I only see two.

Comment: @gj_ Actually, there are only two. In the logcat, the first log is when the dialog box opens, and it is false. The second one is true, because I click "dont show again". The third one is when I navigate **away and back** to the activity, and it says **false** again, and shows the dialog box again.

Comment: If you put just this code in a new project, do you get the same result?

Comment: could you change from .commit() to .apply()? does it change the result ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call dialogPrefs.edit(), you get an Editor instance, that instance was then no longer used and possibly garbage collected. So the next time that you called it, it wasn't saved.

You possibly want to also use dialogPrefs.apply instead of dialogPrefs.commit. Commit is done synchronously and returns whether it is saved successfully, where as apply is asynchronous and much faster (Since most people didn't check for the response anyway)

```
preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor dialogEditor = preferences.edit();
dialogEditor.putBoolean("show", true);
dialogEditor.apply();
```